# When I do not expose IQueryable then I have not to do integration tests

Tags: entity-framework

I have read lots of SO links about unit/integration testing of the entity framework and to sum it all up if I have not misunderstood:

When the repository interface exposes an IQueryable I have to do integration tests (unit tests are not sufficient) because the IQueryable which is linq to entities can be turned into a linq to objects query which can behave totally different which can only be tested having a real database.

When the repository interface exposes only IEnumerable or List it is enough to unit test the repository.

I know it can be very cool to compose an IQueryable in my service without adding many new interface methods...

But if the above is true and I want to avoid integration tests if possible...

What do you think?

Comment: I don't agree with the assertion that if you expose IQueryable results through your repository you must test them with a Db connection. The bigger question is what code are you looking to exercise? Are you wanting to test business logic in your repository (which shouldn't contain much in the way of business logic to start with) or are you wanting to test that the database structure supports the queries being generated by EF based on your model?

Comment: My repositories contain zero business logic therefor I have a service. I want the latter you mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When the repository interface exposes only IEnumerable or List it is
>   enough to unit test the repository.

No. That is misunderstanding. When repository exposes only `IEnumerable` or `List` it is safe to fake or mock it and unit test the logic using your repository. The repository itself must be still covered with integration tests because it defines database queries which must be tested against the real database.

The main reason to hide the query behind the repository is to separate concerns and define strict boundary between application logic and database executed logic (the query). Each logic requires its own tests.

Questions you are referring most probably discussed mocking or faking the EF context / EF sets or repository exposing `IQueryable`. In such case the repository exposes database executed logic into upper layer which makes correct testing much harder. In such case you need to unit test your application logic and somehow fake Linq-to-entities (database logic) with Linq-to-objects. But such tests are not enough to test those queries so you also need integration tests which will duplicate part of your unit tests.

Comment: Ok fine. I understood now. But why should I still unit test the repository if my integration tests cover every repository method? Or is this rather a general debate about integration tests vs unit tests? I know unit tests make it easier/quicker to find the buggy code but just to say in general I think integration tests are enough to cover everything, they are just slower and not that maintainable etc...

Comment: You don't need unit tests to cover repository in general (unless there is some application level logic to test).